# Python error - Invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming, I have a task to run the following file: http://pastebin.com/UmheVyvV with Python, but I get error on line 163:

```
line 163
print filename + " "*(80 - len(filename) - len(ln)) + ln + delim,

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There's a '^' below filename in the error message.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem and be able to run the file? Thanks!

Comment: which version of python ? If 3.x , `print` is a function. SO, you need to do `print(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` with `(`:

```
print filename + " "*(80 - len(filename) - len(ln)) + ln + delim,
#                    ^
```

---

**UPDATE**

The code in the given url is written for Python 2.x. It will not work in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3. the print statement become a function so you need to put parentheses. example:

```
print (1+3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The '^' shows you where the syntax is incorrect. Depending on python version parenthesis should be used.

doc http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html